# How to pass parameters to a method using blocks

Tags: ios, objective-c-blocks

I know If I have a method like this

```
-(void) myMethod:(myCompletion) compblock{
//do stuff
compblock(YES);
}
```

I can call to that method using a block like this

```
[self myMethod:^(BOOL finished) {
if(finished){
    NSLog(@"success");
}
}];
```

If this `myMethod`have several parameters like this

```
-(void)myMethod :(NSMutableURLRequest *)request :(BOOL)isGet :(NSMutableDictionary *)jsonBody :(myCompletion) compblock
```

How can I modify the above block in order to pass several parameters

Please help me

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
-(void)myMethodWithRequest:(NSMutableURLRequest *)request myBool:(BOOL)isGet dictionary:(NSMutableDictionary *)jsonBody  block:(void (^)(NSMutableURLRequest *, BOOL, NSMutableDictionary *))compblock;

-(void)myMethodWithRequest:(NSMutableURLRequest *)request myBool:(BOOL)isGet dictionary:(NSMutableDictionary *)jsonBody  block:(void (^)(NSMutableURLRequest *, BOOL, NSMutableDictionary *))compblock {

compblock(request, isGet, jsonBody);

}
```

Not tested in XCode though. Also, don't leave parameters in your method unnamed, it's a nightmare to read.

I often forget how to properly declare a block, gladly there's a nice [website](http://goshdarnblocksyntax.com/) for that!

Comment: you mean I want to change myMethod? but inside that method I want to assign only the that NSString value to my block. I dont need to assign requst and mutable array to the block

Comment: @IRD It appears I didn't understand your question correctly. It's still unclear to me what you want to achieve. Update your question with more info and try to make it a little more easy to understand.